# Is there any alternative ajv(json-schema validator) for deno?

Tags: deno

I'm looking for a ajv-like json schema validator for deno. Wondering is there any alternative?

Comment: Here's the most relevant Github Issue: https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/issues/1850

Answer (score 6):

You have some options to use none-deno modules.

The easiest way is to use a service like [esm.sh](https://esm.sh) and import it like:

```
import Ajv from 'https://esm.sh/ajv@8.6.1';
import addFormats from 'https://esm.sh/ajv-formats@2.1.0';
const ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true});
addFormats(ajv);
```

[esm.sh](https://esm.sh) even provides .d.ts definitions if available, so you can import types as well.

```
import Ajv, {ValidateFunction} from 'https://esm.sh/ajv@8.6.1';
const validate: ValidateFunction = new Ajv().compile(schema);
```

In some cases, you can even import the raw typescript file directly from git. But [Ajv](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv) imports json files directly, which [deno does not support atm](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/7623).

Comment: To get latest version, just use browser address bar and strip version, like this: `https://esm.sh/ajv`, and it redirects to a later version if available

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an alternative, you can use `ajv`.

`Ajv` [provides a bundle for browsers](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv#using-in-browser): https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/6.12.2/ajv.min.js

All you need to do is download it, save it to your project and add: `export default Ajv` at the bottom of the file.

**ajv.js**

```js
/* ajv 6.12.2: Another JSON Schema Validator */
!function(e){if("object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module) /*....... */
//# sourceMappingURL=ajv.min.js.map

export default Ajv;
```

**index.js**

```js
import Ajv from './ajv.js'

const ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true});

const schema = {
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "type": "string" },
    "bar": { "type": "number", "maximum": 3 }
  }
};

function test(data) {
  const valid = validate(data);
  if (valid) console.log('Valid!');
  else console.log('Invalid: ' + ajv.errorsText(validate.errors));
}


const validate = ajv.compile(schema);

test({"foo": "abc", "bar": 2});
test({"foo": 2, "bar": 4});
```

---

Remember that Deno is a JavaScript runtime, so **any code which uses plain JavaScript**, you'll be able to use it with very little modification, in this case just `export default Ajv`

Comment: Also note that `ajv` has a type definitions file, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajv-validator/ajv/master/lib/ajv.d.ts, so you can get type checking and hints if you prefix the import statement with `// @deno-types="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajv-validator/ajv/master/lib/ajv.d.ts"`

Comment: AJV seems to not work with [Deno Deploy](https://deno.com/deploy), due to it generating code.

Answer (score 1):

Till now, ajv-like schema validator is not available for Deno. However, you can try **value_schema** for schema validation. It has both [Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/value-schema) and [Deno](https://deno.land/x/value_schema) versions.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `value_schema`/`value-schema` is not able to handle JSON schemas but implements it's own way of defining schemas?
Is there some way to generate the `value-schema` code for a JSON schema? To what degree can `value-schema` even offer the capabilities of a JSON schema?

Answer (score 1):

[jtd](https://deno.land/x/jtd@v0.1.0) is a viable alternative. It is a deno native implementation of [JSON Type Definition](https://jsontypedef.com), aka [RFC 8927](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8927), which is an alternative to `json-schema` validation (and thus ajv) but has a similar purpose.